# how shall i find the $n$-th term of this,

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How shall I find the $n$-th term of this:

- $\sqrt{1+2}$
- $\sqrt[3]{1+2+3}$
- $\sqrt[4]{1+2+3+4}$
- $\sqrt[5]{1+2+3+4+5}$
- $\sqrt[6]{1+2+3+4+5+6}$
- $\sqrt[7]{1+2+3+4+5+6+7}$

all the way to $\sqrt[n]{1+2+3+\cdots+(n-2)+(n-1)+n}$.

I couldn't find any ratio or pattern when using finite differences.

Comment: Presumably, you know that $1+2+\cdots+n=n(n+1)/2$, so the $n$th term is $\root n\of{n(n+1)/2}$. What more do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt[n]{1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)+n}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{n(n+1)}2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the fact that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and take the nth root.

Comment: thank u for helping ,it really helped me

Answer (score 0):

As the numbers are in $AP$ : then
$$n\sqrt{1+2+3+4+.......+n}=n\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$$